# Negation of conjunction (non-strict vs strict inequality)

Tags: logic

I have the below conjunction which I need to negate:

$(2−6 = −1\cdot(6−2)) \land (\dfrac 0{10} < 0)$

I think the correct solution is the below:

$(2−6 \neq −1(6−2)) \lor  (\dfrac 0{10} \geq 0)$

The only bit I'm not quite sure of is that why it's non-strict inequality **$\geq$** is the negation of $\lt$ instead of strict inequality **$\gt$** ?

Comment: What kind of logic is this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two real numbers, $a$ and $b$, are related in exactly one of three ways.

$$a<b\quad \text{or}\quad a=b \quad \text{or} \quad a>b.$$
If we negate one of these, the other two remain.

Therefore, the negation of $\frac{0}{10} < 0$ is
$$\frac{0}{10} = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{0}{10} > 0$$.
Which is $\frac{0}{10} \ge 0$

Comment: Beautifully explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The negation of $x<0$ is $x\ge 0.$